# Будет ли google выдавать две страницы, на один запрос?

Tags: seo, google-search

Имеется сайт, в нем страницы на одном языке (перевод не требуется), но переведён сам интерфейс сайта. Язык интерфейса меняется, если например с `domen.com/post` перейти на `domen.com/en/post`, это будет один и тот же контент с разными языком интерфейса, так же поменяется язык у `title`, `description`, `keywords`. Для каждого из этих адресов в sitemap указан url с переводом. В canonical каждый адрес ссылается сам на себя. Для каждого адреса прописаны два hreflang ru и en, и x-default - ru и указаны соответствующие url. Меня смущает одно. Не будет ли для пользователя в google две выдачи (если рассматривать два языка), так как вычитал в документации, что google учитывает больше контент, чем атрибуты вроде `lang`?

[Ссылка на документацию, где это сказано](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=ru)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В этом же руководстве Гугл рекомендует: "Убедитесь, что язык страницы определяется однозначно". Это может конфликтовать с вашим одним языком для главного содержания и разными языками интерфейса и мета тэгов.

Answer (score 0):

- domen.com/post
- domen.com/en/post

Это две разных страницы для Google. По-хорошему, надо переводить контент страницы или закрывать ее от индексации.